# Issues trying to fetch data from PHP JSON multidimensional array with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which, when echoed in PHP, looks like this:

```
{
    "11-12-20":{"visits":0,"pageviews":0}
    "11-12-21":{"visits":0,"pageviews":0}
    "11-12-22":{"visits":0,"pageviews":0}
}// etc.
```

As you can see, the date is the key to the arrays inside the multidimensional array. So I can select an array from the multidimensional array using the date as the key:

```
$my_multi_array['12-12-12'];
```

JSON:

```
$.getJSON('file.php', function(data){
    var test='11-12-29';
    document.write(data.test);
});
```

When I test that in a browser, nothing is printed on the screen. Also, how would I go about looping through the whole of that array in jQuery and use the data inside that array's array.

I've been at this for hours now, and am pretty frustrated.

Comment: can down-voter please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP output that you have echoed is not an array, it's a JSON object without comma separators, which means it's not correctly formed.

If you correct the syntax, you can access the objects in data through the index notation ([]), not the dot operator (.). So instead of accessing `data` like `data.test`, you should try `data[test]`.

Assuming you name your JSON object `myJson`, here's how you can iterate thought it:

```
var myJson = {
    "11-12-20":{"visits":0,"pageviews":0},
    "11-12-21":{"visits":0,"pageviews":0},
    "11-12-22":{"visits":0,"pageviews":0}
}

for (var item in myJson)
{
    alert(myJson[item].visits + ", " + myJson[item].pageviews);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `data[test]`. Your `data.test` is equal to `data["test"]`, and there is no "test" property in your object.